# How to execute parallel/power intensive code on mobile phones with less battery drain?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, parallel-processing

I was asked in an Interview how I would execute parallel/power intensive code on mobile phones without draining the power much.

I had no idea and still have no idea, all I can find on the internet is to have better battery and better processors but I dont think thats the answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the question would be served better on meta than here.

Comment: By definition, it is not possible to "execute... power intensive code... without draining the power much". If it does not "drain the power much", then it is not "power intensive code". If the questioner's concern is the battery level, you can use things like `JobScheduler` to arrange to do background work only when the device is on a charger.